# Loading x number of bits in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

In MIPS we can *load* **words**(32-bits), **half-words**(16-bits) and **byte** (8-bits).

I am curious to know if we can load x number of bits instead?

for example,

if we have a 32 bit word, and I want to extract(load) only the first *x* bits

word = **0001 1001 1000** 0000 0000 0000 0000 1110

load the first 12 bits from word and store into temp

temp = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  **0001 1001 1000**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No architecture I've known support this<sup>1</sup> because it's just useless and will affect the CPU's performance. You can always do it manually by masking the unneeded bits with `AND`

If the address of the variable is contained in `$s0`, you can use this

```
lw   $t0, 0($s0)  # load the value
srlv $t0, $t0, 20 # shift right 20 bits
```

If you want to load the low 12 bits then mask out the high bits away

```
andi $t0, $t0, 0xfff
```

To load a series of bits from arbitrary position, combine shift and bitwise-and like above

---

<sup>1</sup>Updated: x86 can load the low N bits of a value stored at some memory address with `BZHI` in [BMI2 instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI2)